# Very simple c# access modifiers VS form

Tags: c#

This is for a windows form in VS. It says that "newpic" does not exist in current context. I tried to set the access modifier to public with the load event handler method or whatever you call that. But that didn't do it for me. I'm sure its something simple I'm not aware of.
It would be great if I could get "newpic" to be saved in "resources"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace flexland
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bmp=new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.pic1in);
            Bitmap newpic = new Bitmap(bmp);
            int width=bmp.Width;
            int height=bmp.Height;
            Color c=default(Color);
            byte t=10;
            byte t2=10;
            byte rc=50;
            byte gc=50;
            byte bc=50;
            byte rs=10;
            byte gs=10;
            byte bs=10;
            byte rc2=100;
            byte gc2=100;
            byte bc2=100;
            byte rs2=100;
            byte gs2=100;
            byte bs2=100;
            byte rs3=200;
            byte gs3=200;
            byte bs3=200;

            for(int y=0; y<height; y++)
            {
                for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
                {   
                    c=bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                    byte a=c.A;
                    byte r=c.R;
                    byte g=c.G;
                    byte b=c.B;
                    int rl=rc-t;
                    int rh=rc+t;
                    int gl=gc-t;
                    int gh=gc+t;
                    int bl=bc-t;
                    int bh=bc+t;

                    int  rl2=rc2-t2;
                    int  rh2=rc2+t2;
                    int  gl2=gc2-t2;
                    int gh2=gc2+t2;
                    int  bl2=bc2-t2;
                    int bh2=bc2+t2;

                    if((r>rl&&r<rh)&&(r>rl&&r<rh)&&(b>bl&&b<bh))
                    {
                        newpic.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, rs, gs, bs));
                    }
                    else if((r>rl&&r<rh)&&(r>rl&&r<rh)&&(b>bl&&b<bh))
                    {
                        newpic.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, rs2, gs2, bs2));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newpic.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, rs3, gs3, bs3));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ictureBox1.Image =newpic; ////******PROBLEM*****newpic red underline
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its defined in the form load method, not at the class level. it doesn't exist outside of the method you define it in (or more accurately, outside of the `{` and `}` brackets you define it in).

Answer (score 1):

You should make the variable `newpic` accessible to the `button1_Click` event by defining it as variable of the `Form1` instance itself rather than the variable of the event `Form1_Load`

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace flexland
 {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
         public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         Bitmap newpic; //Put newpic here!

         public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.pic1in);
             newpic = new Bitmap(bmp); //don't declare newpic here!
             .... //all other initializations
         }

         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             pictureBox1.Image = newpic; //It should fix the problem
         }       
     }
 }
```